# Finding Minimum Elements for Longest Path in Disjoint Set

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, sets, disjoint-sets, rank

I want to know the minimum number of elements needed to create a tree with the longest path having n edges. How can I approach this problem using the forest implementation of disjoint sets with union by rank and path compression? Would it just be n+1 elements? Or am I missing something? I feel as though n+1 would be too straightforward.

Can anyone provide any insights or tips on how to approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "elements"?  A tree doesn't require any elements.  I don't understand what any particular data structure has to do with this.  Or is this a question about what internal states of a union-find data structure can be achieved by making some sequence of calls to Union and Find?  Can you revise your question to clarify what you are asking?  Perhaps you can tell us where you encountered this task, and quote the original source and provide proper attribution for it, or you can explain the motivation?